# Place FrameLayout between toolbar and bottom bar

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I know perfectly how to do this with relative layout or constraint layout.
But I did not manage to do this with coordinator layout

It seems like the frame layout is overlapped with the top and bottom toolbars.

I need something like 'below' or 'above' tags from the relative layout.
What is the right way to do this kind of layout with the coordinator?

I played with 'app:layout_anchorGravity' but I did not manage to get it right.

All I want to do is to show the fragment inside the frame layout without overlapping. I do not want my fragment to be overlapped from the toolbars, I want to be in between

As you can see from the image, the item number 0, and the item number 1 is not shown, it is behind the toolbar, also with the item number 21, 22
Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/appbar_bottom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
            android:id="@+id/bottombar_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar_bottom"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check updated layout here... It should fixed your issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/appbar_bottom"
            android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar" />

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
                android:id="@+id/bottombar_navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar_bottom"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: you trick with the relative layout inside the coordinator did work. Thanks. I got one more question if you are willing to help, how can I show the snack bar above the bottom toolbar? At the moment it shows over the bottom toolbar, what should I change to start showing above the bottom toolbar ?

Comment: Actually i have never try to change position of snackbar. I think it should always bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

give id to Toolbar as

```
android:id="@+id/header"
```

and give bottom bar as

```
android:id="@+id/footer"
```

now you can place your FrameLayout like this

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Content goes here"
        android:textColor="@color/ash"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</FrameLayout>
```